# C++ multilevel inheritance - Calling Base Constructor Error

Tags: c++, inheritance, multi-level

So I have a fairly complex programm that I dont whant to go into right now. I will include a toy example of the same process and then go over it in more detail.

In my Programm I encounter the Error `constructor for 'Hunter' must explicitly initialize the base class 'WorldObject' which does not have a default constructor` with multilevel inheritance: `WorldObject` -> `Creature` -> `Hunter`.

To recreate the same structure I made the following:

```
class Base
{
protected:
    int a;
public:
    Base(int a): a(a) { print("Base contructed"); }
    ~Base() { print("Base destroyed"); }
    virtual void printData() = 0;
};



class Derived1 : public Base
{
protected:
    int b;
public:
    Derived1(int a, int b): b(b), Base(a) { print("Derived1 contructed"); }
    ~Derived1() { print("Derived1 destroyed"); }
};


class Derived2 : public Derived1
{
protected:
    int c;
public:
    Derived2(int a, int b, int c) : c(c), Derived1(a, b) { print("Derived2 contructed"); }
    ~Derived2() { print("Derived2 destroyed"); }
    virtual void printData(){ //... }
};
```

Here, the constructor of Derived2 class created Derived1 via the initializer list and this in turn constructs Base "indirectly". This works like I expected.

However, in my complex Code, the Hunter class needs to explicitly call the WorldObject constructor. This looks like:

```
Hunter(sf::Texture &texture, float x, float y, sf::Font& font) : 
        WorldObject(texture,x, y, font),
        Creature(texture, x, y, font)
    { //... }
```

Here, The Creature constructor just passes every argument to the WorldObject constructor. WorldObject only has this constructor:

```
WorldObject(sf::Texture& texture, float x, float y, sf::Font& font) : m_sprite(texture)
{ //... }
```

and the used Creature constructor looks like this:

```
    Creature(sf::Texture &texture, float x, float y, sf::Font& font) : 
    WorldObject(texture, x, y, font), 
    NN(n_input_units, n_hidden_units, n_output_units)
{ //... }
```

Why do I need to initialize both WorldObject and Creature directly in my Programm, but in the toy example it works without the explicit Base constructor?

(( The pre-compiler is also complaining that there is no default constructor for WorldObject, and on compiling the above error appears))

Comment: As you see yourself, your real code does not work like the simplified example, so the problem is in your real code, most probably in parts that you did not write here. Try simplifying the real code unless either you realize what is the problem, or unless you come to a short example that you can post here.

Comment: "So I have a fairly complex programm that I dont whant to go into right now" acutally it does not really matter how complex it is, you should try to create a [mcve]

Comment: I think you should include your actual classes instead of `Base`, `Derived1` and `Derived2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that in your *complex* code, `Hunter` directly inherits from `WorldObject` and not indirectly via `Creature`. If `Creature` inherits `WorldObject`, it will *never* be necessary for `Hunter` to pass any parameters to `WorldObject`.

Comment: @D.Niermann (deleted comment, but I leave this here for now, anyways) please post a full, minimal example that reproduces the error, then. I see that `Creature` also inherits from `NN` but this does not change much...
No default constructor is probably a whole different error, could be because you use vector or some other container

Comment: My Creature Class virtually inherited from WorldObject, which made it necessary to also give parameters for WorldObject in the Hunter constructor. Now I fixed it by making it non virtual. I have to look up virtual inheritance again to understand why it fixed the error. Thanks for your answer still, it made me question my code enough to look at everything again :)